# How can i show the api response in my component with toast

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, callback

I call api rest with apex, in a lightning component: i have this code in apex class,

```
public static String agentesCrear(String agentesJson){
    String bodyReq = agentesJson.replaceAll('\\[', '').replaceAll('\\]','');
    System.debug('DatoAgente : ' + bodyReq);
    
    string res = '';
    Http http = new Http(); 
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('URL');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    request.setBody(bodyReq);
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    
        if(response.getStatusCode() != 200){
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
            response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus() + ' - ' + response.getBody());
            res = response.getBody();
            
        }else{
            System.debug(response.getBody());
             res = response.getBody();
            
        }
        return res; 
}
```

and i have this in my helper lightning component:

```
 action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
  var state = response.getState();
  
    
  if (state == "SUCCESS") {
    console.log("ok");  
    var errorRes = response.getReturnValue();
      console.log("errorRes :",errorRes);
      var tst = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        tst.setParams({
      
      title: 'Mensaje',
      message: errorRes,
      type: 'success',
      duration : 8000,
      mode:'sticky'
  });
  tst.fire();
```

this is response in my console:
[image: Description of response in browser console]

toast show me this message and not response what i need i dont know why.
[image: Toast message]

Comment: A simple solution would be stringify the response in your component controller and then pass to toast event as message supports a text-only string.

Comment: how you do that? json.stringify not found :/ the gave me same response with this keys }}